# Total vs. Partial derivatives in kinetics

Tags: kinetics, notation

I've recently seen partial derivatives in the velocity definition but in most cases is with total derivatives (infinitesimal change of concentration over infinitesimal change of time).
Maybe is more accurate to use partial derivatives because it shows that is only differentiation with respect time and not the other variables (which ones?).
Is this even remarkable or is just some change of notation?

[image: Figure that shows how partial derivatives are used in CINÉTICA QUÍMICA, A. G. UREÑA, Ed. Síntesis, 2005]

Comment: The other variables can be the temperature, the pressure, the viscosity, the concentration of substances not taking part to the reaction, etc.

Comment: Why viscosity?.

Comment: Viscosity may affect the rate of molecular collisions, as there are stronger intermolecular forces.

Comment: A chemical reaction has a rate that tends to zero if the "solution" is like honey, then like glue, then like a solid.

Comment: I searched for examples of $$\frac{\partial [A]}{\partial t}$$ and could not find them. Where did you see these partial derivatives? Could you edit your question to provide the sources.

Comment: i am not familiar with this use of partial derivatives, but it wouldn't surprise me if it were either A) in a multi-order reaction and a diff eq is being described with rate dependence on other concentrations (catalyst loading, perhaps?) or B) a chemical engineering context where homogeneous mixing of solutions are not presumed and thus mechanical stresses, boundary conditions, etc. are applicable.

Comment: I've added a picture that shows an example of partial derivatives in *Cinética química*, Ángel González Ureña, Ed Síntesis (2005). ISBN: 978-84-773890-7-1.             Is in Spanish, this part is about consecutive reactions, and it uses a different notation as he defines [A] as (Ao-x).

Comment: Now that I see the source, I think it is just unusual notation without significance. In the example, there is only one variable used for differentiation, time. I don't think it is wrong but rather unexpected and therefor puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the ideal gas state equation as an example, in the form $V=f(n,p,T)$, then we use a partial derivative $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{n,p}$.

But if we use it in a closed, isobaric scenario as $V=f(T)$, with $n, p$ implicitly constant, then we can use normal/total derivative $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} V}{\mathrm{d} T}\right)$

The distinguishing of both cases is kind of formal, depending on if you formally consider the other independent variables explicitly or not.

Comment: Ok, but in this case the function was concentration, so all the variables that @Maurice said (p,T, viscosity, etc...) are what concentration depends on?

Comment: I suppose it's concentration because is in the velocity definition

Comment: And about your answer, you mean that when total derivatives in the velocity defifnition are used is because the other variables are constant, don't you?

Comment: Then apply the example on concentration or generally on any independent and dependent variables. The topic is rather mathematical than chemical.